# Cartoon where military protagonists stop a train by shooting glue (?) at the wheels

Tags: story-identification, tv, cartoon

I remember watching a cartoon on VHS pre-2006 where some military-looking protagonists are trying to stop a train from crashing into something (a port or some other facility). They end up stopping the train by one of them shooting a rapidly-solidifying white substance at some of the train's wheels, stopping the wheels from turning, braking the train, and stopping it.

I remember one of the characters having a gun or some other techy prosthetic for an arm.

I remember it being in English, and was most probably an American production. It could be a late-90s early-2000s Saturday morning cartoon, the production value wasn't that high.

What was this cartoon? What episode was it?

Comment: I suspect I know what cartoon this was from, but I have to dig out a DVD box set to check. This might take some time... :D (Or I could be completely wrong...)

Comment: No luck. I thought this might've been C.O.P.S. / Cyber-C.O.P.S., but while that show had several episodes with train robberies, it looks like none featured the train being stopped by expanding foam/glue/etc.